# What financial forecasting methods are available for evaluating the profitability of a cash flow?

Tags: finance, reference-request

I'm sorry for this question. I'm looking for forecasting methods for evaluating the profitability of a cash flow

I'm not experienced with this branch of the economics, I've done some searches in the documentation, but I couldn't find much stuff.

Does Mathematica have something better than Excel IRR? Any suggestion on where to look will be appreciated. I will use the suggested references to improve this question.

Comment: See the guides on [`Financial Computation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Finance.html) and [`Actuarial Computation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ActuarialComputation.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon: thanks a lot